# ruamel.yaml loses anchor and skips aliases after the first alias on the same level when dumping

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Given this YAML:

```yaml
---
sp-database: &sp-database
  DATABASE_NAME: blah
  DATABASE_PORT: 5432
  DATABASE_SCHEMA: public
  DATABASE_USERNAME: foo
  DATABASE_DRIVER: bar
  DATABASE_TYPE: pg

rabbit: &rabbit
  RABBIT_PORT: 5672
  RABBIT_USERNAME: foo

sp-env: &sp-env
  <<: *sp-database
  <<: *rabbit
  REDIS_PORT: 6379
```

when I read this code in and dump it out:

```py
def blah(self):
    values_file = './src/values.yaml'
    with open(values_file, 'r') as stream:
        data = self.yaml.load(stream)
    values_file='./src/values1.yaml'
    with open(values_file, 'w') as file:
        self.yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
        self.yaml.dump(data, file)
```

The closest solution I found was this:
[How to generate multiple YAML anchors and references in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73806159/how-to-generate-multiple-yaml-anchors-and-references-in-python)

in which I did change the alias usage to this:

```yaml
sp-env: &sp-env
  <<: [ *sp-database, *rabbit ]
  REDIS_PORT: 6379
```

and it works but I want to figure out why it's not working with the sequential aliases, not the array subscripted aliases.

Comment: I assume your code throws an error, as it is unclear how `self.yaml` is created this is not necessarily so. You should consider using `pathlib.Path()` instances to make your code cleaner. That also makes sure your files are opened correctly, for writing UTF-8 **binary** files, potentially preventing extra conversions (YAML is slow enought as it is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YAML specification describes mappings](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#The [YAML specification describes mappings](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#mapping) quite clearly:

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key/value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

Although `ruamel.yaml` always has happely ignored the "unordered" part in there, to be able to keep
the keys in the output in the same order, it doesn't ignore the fact that your input
contains non-unique keys. Since what you you call "array subscripted aliases", are using duplicate keys this throws an error:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

    
file_in = Path('values.yaml')
file_out = Path('values.yaml')
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
try:
    data = yaml.load(file_in)
except Exception as e:
    print('exception:', e)
else:
    yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
exception: while constructing a mapping
  in "values.yaml", line 14, column 9
found duplicate key "<<"
  in "values.yaml", line 16, column 3

To suppress this check see:
   http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#duplicate-keys

Duplicate keys will become an error in future releases, and are errors
by default when using the new API.
```

As it is not allowed to have duplicate keys, it is unclear what to expect if you load something with a library that doesn't
follow the standard. Assume that a non-merge key appears twice and such a faulty library process the key/value pairs in the
order that the keys appear in the YAML file. If it puts each key/value pair in a Python `dict` (without checking if the key already exists) the value from the second occurence overwrites the one from the first.

YAML:

```
- a: 1
- b: 2
- a: 3
```

would give the Python `dict`: `{a: 3, b: 2}`. It should be clear that if that library would use some stack to first gather all
the key/value pairs and process them by popping the value for `a` would be different and that would *still get the
same result after loading for valid YAML*

Processing the merge key makes this more complex. The [merge key specification](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) states:

> If the value associated with the key is a single mapping node, each of its key/value pairs is inserted into the current mapping, unless the key already exists in it. If the value associated with the merge key is a sequence, then this sequence is expected to contain mapping nodes and each of these nodes is merged in turn according to its order in the sequence. Keys in mapping nodes earlier in the sequence override keys specified in later mapping nodes.

You implement the semantics for the merge key can be implemented by first populating
the Python dict with the key/values from the merge key so you don't have to check for "unless the key already exists", and then potentially overwriting them with those of the keys that
occur in the mapping with the dict. If you don't want to
check
for a merge key up front, you can process the "normal" keys and when you encounter a merge key, only add the key/value pairs from the merge
for which the key is not yet in the dict.

In both cases this leads to the situation in which you have a dict in the making. that might have some keys that can be overwritten by keys you
process for that mapping later on (i.e. those coming from a merge) and those that should throw an error (i.e. duplicate keys).
Failing to check for the duplication might give you faulty data (accepting duplicates where it shouldn't).

When the value for a merge key consists of a sequence of mapping nodes (which often are, but don't have to be aliases)
the processing order matters and is explicitly specified. Values for keys occuring in mappings earlier in the sequence
are taken. In your second YAML example that means you'll get the value `5432` for `DATABASE_PORT`), in your
first example it is not clear what that value would be as there should be no ordering associated with the keys.
In that case (assuming no exception is thrown) `*rabbit` could be processed before `*sp-database` or after it, and
the way it is processed (as described above) would also influence the outcome.

By the spec requiring unique keys, all of this processing order mess is prevented. But if a library ignores that requirement
it will still get results, but those are implementation dependent. They problems lies in the fact that these
results are probably consistent and some people (who don't read the specs), start to rely on them. So
then you're processing something that is almost, but quite unlike, YAML and you might have to continue to
allow your library to rely on that, instead of following the spec, at least
until the next major version number change.

Comment: Thank you for the lengthy for very insightful response!!! I've decided to go with the sequence syntax (array notation) to resolve the duplicate merge key issue. Marking this as the answer!